# IPython "enter" inside function definition always execute code

Tags: ipython

Fresh install of Anaconda on Window 10 WSL, I can't seem to be able to define multiline function.

Doing on IPython

```
def foo():
    a = 1
```

If my cursor is after the `1` and I press "enter" I expect it to create new line and continue with the definition, but it's executing the code instead.

IPython 7.0.1, is this a new bug?

Comment: I have this same issue on Manjaro—haven't been able to find anything about it via Google (except this, now).

Comment: I just updated to IPython 7.1.1 (via `conda`) and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I can confirm it worked for me as well.